# android- stream is closed when using URLConnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've an asynctask , this is the code inside background :

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(urls);
                Log.v("this", urls);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String lineC;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((lineC = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(lineC );
                }
                Log.v("this",sb.toString() + " I need this for something else");

                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("content");
                    Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
                    if (i == 0)
                        random = line.getTextContent();
                    else if (i == 1)
                        topsell = line.getTextContent();
                    else if (i == 2)
                        jadidtarin = line.getTextContent();
                    else if (i == 3)
                        pishnahad = line.getTextContent();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                goterror = true;
                Log.v("this", e.getMessage() + "eror");
            }
```

When I remove these lines , it works fine and I get no problem.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String lineC;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((lineC = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(lineC );
                }
```

I don't close anything but when I run the code, I get this error "Stream is closed" , I don't know why .

How can I solve this problem ? as I said in the code, I need to save the whole returned value .

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try using `HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: @UmaKanth thanks for the reply ,i've tried and still the same

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Use

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Why? I used InputStreamReader in many of my projects and it worked fine.

Comment: May there you were using from the local storage, But when it comes to network connection you should always used BufferedInputStream with BufferedReader

Comment: @zeus thanks for the reply , but I get this error :  Error:(133, 53) error: no suitable constructor found for BufferedReader(BufferedInputStream)
constructor BufferedReader.BufferedReader(Reader,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor BufferedReader.BufferedReader(Reader) is not applicable
(actual argument BufferedInputStream cannot be converted to Reader by method invocation conversion)

Comment: @donalddraper can you please post ur code. That would really help